# This if condition is false when comparing array to string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a FOR loop and an IF statement that checks each line for a certain word in a txt document. However when the loop gets to a line that holds the value 'header' the IF statement does not think it is true.

txt file

```
header
bods
#4f4f4f
30
100
1
text
this is content for the page
#efefef
10
300
2
img
file/here/image.png
300
500
filler
3
header
this is header text
#4f4f4f
30
100
4
```

php file

```
$order = array();
$e = 0;
$h = 0;
$headerCount = 0;
$textCount = 0;
$imgCount = 0;

//Open file putting each line into an array
$textFile = fopen("test.txt","r+");
$inTextFile = fread($textFile, filesize("test.txt"));
$arrayFile = explode("\n", $inTextFile);
$arrayFileSize = sizeof($arrayFile);
$elementCount = $arrayFileSize / 6;

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayFileSize; $x++) {

    if ($arrayFile[$x] == "header") {

        echo $x;
        echo " Yes : ".$arrayFile[$x] . "<br>"; 
        $headerCount++;

    }
    else {

        echo $x;
        echo " No : " . $arrayFile[$x] . "<br>"; 

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If `== 'header'` isn't true, that means the value isn't actually "header". It probably has some whitespace before or after it. `var_dump()` the value to see in more detail what it really is.

Comment: `explode("\n", $inTextFile);`  there's probably other whitespace characters involved in each newline. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: I would have used [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), instead of `fopen/fread`

Comment: @deceze I updated so you can see the var_dump

Comment: Quite obviously there's some whitespace there…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Billy. There are two solutions you can try: using the [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function of [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Using `trim()` will remove any leading or trailing spaces from a string:

```
if (trim($arrayFile[$x]) == "header") {...}
```

Using `strpos()` can help you check if word "header" exists anywhere in a string. If the given word does not exists than it will return `false`:

```
if (strpos($arrayFile[$x], "header") !== false) {...}
```